# calling a method in worker thread from main thread freezing app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have my main thread which is creating an instance of a new thread. this new thread creates an instance of a metronome. if I try to call the metronomes play() method through a button click on the main thread then the metronome starts but the whole app freezes.

main activity code:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

MetroThread metronome;


/*** onCreate ***/  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

metronome = new MetroThread();
metronome.start();
}

/*** button clicks ***/

public void st44BtnClick(View v)
{
if(metronome.myMetronome==null)
{
    metronome.playMetronome();
}
else if(metronome.myMetronome!=null)
{
    metronome.stopMetronome();
}
}
```

and the metronome thread code:

```
public class MetroThread extends Thread
{   
//create instance of the metronome
public Metro myMetronome;

public void run()
{
System.out.println("metroThread started");
}

/*** play metronome ***/
public void playMetronome()
{
myMetronome = new Metro();
myMetronome.bpm = 200;
myMetronome.beat = 7;
myMetronome.beatSound = 2000;
myMetronome.sound = 2600;
myMetronome.play();
}
/*** stop metronome ***/
public void stopMetronome()
{
    myMetronome.stop();
myMetronome = null;
}
```

}

if instead of using a button click to call the playMetronome method i simply call the method from the run() in the metronome thread, it works fine and does not lock up the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a method is associated with a thread object doesn't mean that it is run on that specific thread. In fact in this case your `Metronome` thread has actually exited immediately, it ends as soon as you return from the `run()` method.

When you call the `playMetronome` method you are actually calling it from the button click thread.

What you need to do is send a signal to the `Metronome` thread that then causes it to start playing... or create a new `Metronome` and start the thread whenever they press the button and have the thread always play the sound.

Comment: would it be best practice in this case to start the metronome thread with each click of the button? i was worried about threads building up and continuing to run in the background.

Comment: @user2145312 The threads disappear when they exit the run - so there is no build up. There is some overhead to creating threads though so it is better to avoid it. You also need to consider what happens if someone hits the button lots of times repeatedly. You should investigate `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The methods are executed in Thread that's actually calling the Thread. Since you are calling those from the UI Thread, those are executed in the UI Thread. Try calling `playMetronome` from the `run()`'s method

Answer (score 0):

Only code called from `run()` of your worker thread will really works in separate thread. Now you are creating second thread, but make all operations in main thread (because you are call `play()` from it)

You can:

1) add boolean flag `isPlaying` into your second thread and change it value from mainThread

2) start infinite loop in second thread's `run()` and sometimes check this flag here.